# how to create customer using custom rest api Magento 2.4.4

Tags: customer-account, model, magento2.4.4, interface, customapi

I have to create custom rest api for create customer programmatically in Magento-2.4.4.
so anyone have an idea then share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer to this URL, here all the method is mentioned on how we can create a custom API and how we can pass customer object to create programmatically.

https://rocktechnolabs.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-api-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you for sharing but i want to create customer using custom api interface and model classes and by creating custom getter and setter methods, and i don't want to create customer using magento's default api.